# Cannot open Update Manager

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, update-manager, steam

I am trying to install Intel drivers on Steam and when I try to open the Update Manager I get this message 'E:Malformed line 6 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'

I'm also very new to Linux considering I got Ubuntu yesterday. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you have a malformed line in /etc/apt/sources.list, could you please post the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: What does `cat /etc/apt/sources.list  | head -8` produce? *(This will just output the first 8 lines of the file)*. If unreadable as a normal user (Permission Error), you may need to run `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list  | head -8`

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed line in /etc/apt/sources.list to solve this issue use the following -

```
wget https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8850924/sources.list

sudo mv ./sources.list /etc/apt

sudo apt-get update
```

hope it will work.

Comment: Wonderful! It's all good now, thank you very much.

Comment: instead of mentioning thanks you can accept it as answer and up vote. avoid mentioning it for  making intersection simple and straight to the point.